# Remove extra bits from facebook album URL using php or javascript

Tags: php, javascript, regex, facebook

Im just using the graph.facebook.com code to display photos from an album but i want the user to be able to paste the URL from their album and then using a php regular expression or javascript i would like to remove everything but the album id so i can display the photos.

If a user pastes this to their users MYSQL table:

```
https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.10152107362775359.906732.14226545341&type=3
```

What would be the best way to retrieve only the numbers after a. and before where the next . starts.

basically i need this: 10152107362775359

I know i can get everything that set=

```
$notclean = 'a.10152107362775359.906732.14226545341';
```

but now how do i make

```
$notclean = '10152107362775359';
```

Thanks in advance :)
Jonny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`explode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function:

```
$str = 'a.10152107362775359.906732.14226545341';
$arr = explode(".",$str);
$notclean = $arr[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

[Split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) it at the periods.

```
var parts = 'a.10152107362775359.906732.14226545341'.split('.');
```

This gives you an array

```
["a", "10152107362775359", "906732", "14226545341"]
```

Then get the 2nd element of the array

```
$notclean = parts[1];
```

For PHP use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) instead of split.

```
$parts = explode('.', $notclean);
```

Comment: Your answer mixes php and javascript.

Comment: Actually Daedalus is right?, but i realized i could use $valArr       = explode(".", $notclean); from what sachleen posted. Is there even an easier way?

Comment: Oops. didn't notice it was PHP. Yeah, same thing, only use explode instead of split.

Comment: js : notclean.split('.')[1]  ;  if any checking has to be done server side use is_int()

Comment: Do **not** use `is_int`. The number is too big for integer and it will return false. use [`is_numeric`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) instead.